# Inserting JSON into a PostgreSQL database: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert a JSON file in a JSONB column using PostgreSQL in a python script.

First I loaded csv files into dataframes, filled a few NaN and dumped that into a JSON:

```
df = pd.read_csv("casos.csv", names=["casos"], encoding ="utf-8", engine='python')
df2 = pd.read_csv("corregimientos.csv", encoding="utf-8", engine='python')
df2 = df2.replace(np.nan, None, regex=True)
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df], axis = 1)


for column in range(0,3,1):
   for row in range(len(df2)):
     if df2.iloc[row,column] is not None:
         val = df2.iloc[row,column]
     elif df2.iloc[row,column] is None:
         df2.iloc[row,column] = val


jCorreg = df2.to_json(orient = "records", lines = True)


jCorreg = [json.loads(line) for line in open('corregimientos.json', 'r')]
```

Here is my code:

```
cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE casos (
                    id serial NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
                    nlcasos JSONB NOT NULL);''')

cur.execute('INSERT INTO casos (nlcasos) VALUES (%s)',jCorreg)
```

When I try to insert the data from the JSON, I get the error mentioned above.

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue. I also tried to do the insert like this:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO casos (nlcasos) VALUES ("'+jCorreg+'")')
```

But ended up with another error, which I'm assuming is because it believes that the end of my string is the other (").

```
SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "provincia"
LINE 3:         "provincia": "Bocas del Toro",
```

The JSON jCorreg file looks like this:

```
{"provincia":"Bocas del Toro","distrito":"Almirante","corregimientos":"Puerto Almirante","sede del distrito":"Puerto Almirante","casos":303}
{"provincia":"Bocas del Toro","distrito":"Almirante","corregimientos":"Barriada Guaym\u00ed","sede del distrito":"Puerto Almirante","casos":386}
{"provincia":"Bocas del Toro","distrito":"Almirante","corregimientos":"Barrio Franc\u00e9s","sede del distrito":"Puerto Almirante","casos":104}
```

And so on.

Comment: Read the docs [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). Hint, think tuple/list.

Comment: what's the `jCorreg` look like?

Comment: I should have added to previous comment [JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

Comment: Please show us what jCorreg looks like by including python code that sets it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing a few things.
I turned the jCorreg json into a dict using json.loads()

```
jCorreg = [json.loads(line) for line in open('corregimientos.json', 'r')]
```

After that, I just added a json.dumps() in [] to my insert sentence for the database with a for:

```
for line in jCorreg:
      cur.execute('''INSERT INTO casos (nlcasos) VALUES (%s)''', [json.dumps(line)])
```

I also tried to just change the insert sentence to:

```
for line in jCorreg:
      cur.execute('''INSERT INTO casos (nlcasos) VALUES (%s)''', [line])
```

Without changing the JSON into a dict and it also worked.